# What are recommended filters for using Pagespeed along with Drupal 7 (and Advagg enabled)?

Tags: performance

We are planning to integrate Google Pagespeed module in our Drupal 7 site which is already using [Advanced for CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) (Advagg).

Based on the inputs at https://www.drupal.org/node/2182289#comment-8421621 , it seems that Pagespeed CSS/JS filters are not needed since the same job is done by Advagg. Pagespeed has other useful filters for image optimization and inlining critical css.

**My question**: If someone is using Pagespeed along with Drupal and Advagg, can you share the [Pagespeed filters](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filters) that you are currently using or would recommend? If you are using Pagespeed with Drupal but without Advagg, please share your filter recommendations.

I have been searching extensively on this topic but couldn't find much practical information on using Pagespeed along with Drupal.

Comment: Can you share the Pagespeed filters that you ended up using? We have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Every site is different. I recommend extensive testing. http://www.webpagetest.org/ is one of the better sites for testing the frontend and seeing what options are best for you're site. Be sure to test more than just the frontpage & look at the connection view; using the bundler you can adjust this a little bit, try a bundle of 1 or even 10. Point is you'll need to experiment to get the best results. The modifier has lots of things you can do to tweak things; deferring the js is one of the better options in my opinion.

I've heard that google pagespeed has a +-20% difference; it works better or worse depending on various factors. Give it a try and be sure to test!

Work on inline css is being done btw: https://www.drupal.org/project/css_delivery

Comment: Useful info. I checked out https://www.drupal.org/project/css_delivery. It generates critical css during build time and which is used across whole site. Google Pagespeed does it using instrumented beacon which generates the critical css in the user browser and passes it back to server. I am not sure if they generate it per page or use beacon to gather more data. Critical css is important to us and CSS Delivery module looks promising. Thanks for the pointers.